# Change URL for wagtail blog index page

Tags: django, django-urls, wagtail

I currently have a website where the home page at [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) is the wagtail blog index page

I wish to move the blogindex page to another url

I can easily have a different homepage by amending my urls.py file:

```
#original
path("", include(wagtail_urls))

#new
path(
     "",
     TemplateView.as_view(template_name="pages/newhomepage.html"),
     name="newhomepage",
    ),
```

However I would like the blogindex page available at e.g. myste.com/blog but I am not sure how to go about this. Adding the following to urls.py does not do it

```
path("blog/", include(wagtail_urls))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of changes in project required to achieve this.

Firstly, create a `urls.py` file inside your specific app, this will be different from the one that you should already have alongside `wsgi.py`, `asgi.py`, etc. and it will only store app specific urls.

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('test/', index, name='generalized-test-url'),
]
```

Now, you should render the template inside your view.

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'pages/newhomepage.html', context)
```

Lastly, in your root `urls.py` file, you need to include the app urls. Lets say your app name is `blog`.

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```